# python installs with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to using Python, so I may be using the wrong terminology here, so please bear with me.

I understand that if you install a python package using pip, that it runs the `setup.py` file associated in the top level of that package.

If the `setup.py` file has parameters to change the way the installation runs, how do you specify them when using a `pip install` command?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to customize in the installation? It's possible `pip` already has an argument for that.

Comment: I want the `pip install` to run as if I had instead issued this command: `python setup.py build server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`--global-option` or `--install-option`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides) to pass options to `setup.py`.

Comment: Thank you - using the command `pip install pkgname --install-option "server"` appears to have done the trick! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about **pip install** and **argument handling** in this documentation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides)

Comment: And this section held the answer: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides